# Indexed DB storage

Tags: html, github, unreal-blueprint

I need to enable Indexed DB storage for HTML build but it requires Github source to enable (Tool tips). 
I tried to source control it, and GitHub deskstop but nothing.

Do you have any idea how can y enable the indexed DB storage?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not completely clear.

So far my understanding index db doesn't required any extra plugin. 
Its supported from Chrome 69 ( this is what is tested ) older version also supporting indexedDB.

**Edge** :
To get all feature you may need MS RS4 with Edge Latest version to see the records you may have to install Microsoft Edge Dev tools

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Try this code to see if your browser supports it.

```
if (!window.indexedDB) {
    console.log("Your browser doesn't support IndexedDB.");
} else {
    console.log("Your browser supports IndexedDB.");
}
```

if it does, you can start building it. I don't think there is any need for enabling anything.